# Remove all event emitter listeners, except most recent

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

Looking to find a way to remove all listeners except for the most recently added listener.

So for process.stdin, we might do

```
process.stdin.on('readable',function a(){});
process.stdin.on('readable',function b(){});
process.stdin.on('readable',function c(){});
```

I want to remove callbacks a and b, but leave c.

However, in this case I don't have a reference to a or b, I want to do something like:

```
while(process.stdin.listenerCount('readable') > 1){
   process.stdin.removeListener('readable');
}
```

but I think you need to pass a function in. Any way around this?

Comment: If you want to remove listeners, then you must pass in the function that was used when it was added.  And, since you need the function, it can't be an anonymous function - it must be a named function that is declared in a common scope so you have the same reference when removing it as when it was added.

Comment: You're definitely right. Seems weird that if you call removeListener('event-name') without a function as a second argument, that it wouldn't just pop the oldest listener off the array

Comment: Weird?  I don't think so. It's a coding integrity thing.  If you don't have a reference to the function, you're not allowed to remove the listener.  Emitters are designed to be used by many including external code, not only within your own code.  You could wrap your own override for `.on()` that saves the listener references so you could then use them to remove handlers as desired.  Not hard to implement that.

Comment: I am dealing with a library, just don't have a reference to the listener callbacks they have attached. But have access to the event emitter object. Sure it might have to do with public/private scope.

Comment: Then, do what I suggested.  Install an override for `.on()` on your eventEmitter object so you can save the function references to be used later to remove listeners.  You're wishing for a feature that doesn't exist, but you can code a work-around yourself.

Comment: Not sure if I get access to the event emitter until after the callbacks are registered, but just so I understand, you are saying to monkey patch the on function for my particular event emitter? If so, that makes sense, if not please explain.

Comment: Yep, monkey patch `.on()` before the other listeners are installed.  Or, go study [the source code of EventEmitter](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js) and see if you can get access to the instance data to add a method to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a copy of handlers for a particular event via [`eventEmitter.listeners()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_listeners_eventname). However, you really should not rely on them being in a particular order.

Here is one such solution that currently works:

```
process.stdin.listeners('readable').forEach(function(fn) {
  if (process.stdin.listenerCount('readable') > 1)
    process.stdin.removeListener('readable', fn);
});
```

If you know the name of the one function you want to keep, then you can instead just branch on `fn.name` instead, like:

```
process.stdin.listeners('readable').forEach(function(fn) {
  if (fn.name !== 'c')
    process.stdin.removeListener('readable', fn);
});
```

One thing to also be aware of is that if you remove these listeners from a `'readable'` event handler, then the other listeners will still be called for that particular event (but not future events). This is because the listeners for an event name are cloned before any of them are called during `.emit()`.